# Missing "Proceed without enrollment policy" When Generating Certificate Enrollment Policy

Tags: certificate, csr, digital-signatures

I am trying to follow the instructions [listed here](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO29005.html). But when I get to the step:

> 15. Select the option to Proceed without enrollment policy > Click Next.

I see:

[image]

No "Proceed without enrollment policy" is visible. Why? When I google around for this I don't see any references to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you chose `All Tasks -> Advanced Operations -> Create Custom Request` menu, not `All Tasks - Request New Certificate`.

First menu item will include "proceed without policies", second will not.